# Big Data Database on top of OpenStack Swift

Tags: cassandra, hbase, openstack-swift

Is it possible to have a database like Cassandra or any other on top of openstack swift so there is no need to worry about data size? Is this a common approach or is several small servers the better option?

There ***was*** MagnetoDB, but it says everywhere that it is no longer maintained.

I know hadoop can have an openstack backend and Hbase could potentially work on top of that but I don't know if that's actually the case.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Openstack Swift is an object(file + path + metadata) storage and eventually consistent. You can't update the file. You have to upload a new one and overwrite the one that is already there. So probably you wont use it for database storage. It looks like you need a block storage. Ceph may be useful.